# How do I get and set reward points programatically in Magento Enterprise Edition?

Tags: magento

I've had a good look around, but I can't figure out how to get and set reward points in Magento Enterprise Edition

How do I do something like this:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);

Mage::getModel('enterprise_reward/reward')->setPoints($customer, $points);

$points = Mage::getModel('enterprise_reward/reward')->getPoints($customer);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. Do something like the following:

```
public function getPoints($customer_id = false) {
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
    $reward = Mage::getModel('enterprise_reward/reward')
    ->setCustomer($customer)
    ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())
    ->loadByCustomer();
    $balance = $reward->getPointsBalance();
    return $balance;
}


public function setPoints($customer_id = false, $points = false, $comment = 'Adjustment', $action = 0) {       
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);

    $reward = Mage::getModel('enterprise_reward/reward')
    ->setCustomer($customer)
    ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())
    ->loadByCustomer();

    $reward->setPointsBalance($points)
           ->setAction($action) // Enterprise_Reward_Model_Reward::REWARD_ACTION_ADMIN
           ->setComment($comment)
           ->updateRewardPoints();

    $history = Mage::getModel('enterprise_reward/reward_history')
            ->setReward($reward)->prepareFromReward()->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the accepted answer to cause a lot of errors, such as double points.

Here's the solution I came up wth

```
/*REWARD POINTS ADD START*/

$customerId = 1;
$order_id = 100000689;
$points = 10;

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);

$reward = Mage::getModel('enterprise_reward/reward')
      ->setCustomer($customer)
      ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())
          ->loadByCustomer();                    

$reward->setPointsDelta($points)
   ->setAction(Enterprise_Reward_Model_Reward::REWARD_ACTION_REVERT)
   ->setActionEntity($order)
   ->setComment('Added from affiliate program')
   ->updateRewardPoints();

/*END*/
```

This way it created the points, has the ActionEntity, updates the balance correctly and sets the history/